# AES - link between decryption/encryption speed and encryption keys per second

Tags: encryption, aes, aes-gcm

I was reading an apparently [interesting article](https://scrambox.com/article/brute-force-aes/) about the security of AES-256 in terms of brute force attacks.

The article says

> We benchmarked a top-of-the-line, high performance 2015 MacBook Pro with Intel Core i7 ... it could decrypt using AES-256 GCM ... 1024MiB/sec, or 2^30 bytes per second.

Then

> AES uses a 16 byte block size (2^4), so on average, a single high performance PC can encrypt 2^(30-4) = 226 blocks per second.

And that's fine.
But then

> That means it can also try 2^26 different encryption keys per second.

I fail, from my ignorant POV, to link the decryption/encryption speed with the sentence "encryption keys per second".
Maybe it's a language barrier thing. Could someone clarify what the article means with that?

Comment: If you have both the plaintext and ciphertext you can try to encrypt one block of the plaintext with a key and check the ciphertext for equality. Keep trying different keys and you'll do approximately 2^26 per second. This is ignoring the overhead of generating keys to try and setting up the cipher. But the order of magnitude is about right.

Comment: @Marc understood! Thanks. However what's the point of this "benchmark" if you have the plaintext at your disposal? I don't see it mentioned in the article.

Comment: It's known as a [known plaintext attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack). If you don't know the plaintext but have some information about the original data (eg: some parts of the content, file format, etc...), you can use that to check if the attempted key is correct. But all of this is digging into specific details, the article is just trying to illustrate how strong AES-256 is, not dig into cryptanalysis techniques.

Comment: @Marc that sounds reasonable obviously. Thanks again for the clarifications.